# Using vim with files that have extended attributes - how to avoid segfault error and preserve extended attributes?

Tags: vim

I am on a Mac and use Vim 7.3.

I've known this issue for a while: If I do "ls -l" and see that some files have the "@" next to the name, e.g.,

```
 -rw-r--r--@  1 john  staff    152 Dec 12 19:52 requirements.txt
```

Then that means that this file has extended attributes - like special properties stored for that file, perhaps by Dropbox so the icon can look special, or perhaps something by another application for indexing purposes.

When editing a file with vim, when I save, sometimes I get this "Segmentation fault: 11" error.

My solution before has been to run this command to remove the extended attributes on the file:

```
xattr -c <filename>
```

Then I wouldn't get this error anymore.

**However, is there a way to preserve the extended attributes with no errors while still using vim as my editor?** Many programs these days add these extended attributes on things, and I feel that maybe I shouldn't be tampering with them. (I think currently Dropbox adds them to all synced files... so clearly, removing extended attributes repeatedly is too tedious and probably not good practice.)

Comment: Segfaults are bugs. Please report this to vim-dev `:h bugs`. Please check if it still happens in the current version first (We are on 7.4 with a lot of patches)

Comment: I know Vim (in some configurations anyway) actually writes a new file and then deletes the original and renames the new one; I'm not sure if that preserves extended attributes.

Comment: Okay, for the time being, I have upgraded to 7.4, and will update this post if the error still occurs. So far so good though. Thanks.